# RSpec and Capybara setup, have_no_content doesn't seem to be working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, tdd

I'm creating an app where I have a simple delete record on the index of the records once a user logs in.  When I don't have the user logging in under my rspec specs, the delete works.  Meaning that the has_no_content test returns true.  But once I put in place the authentication required to access the index of records, the test fails.  Any thoughts?

```
before do
  @records = Factory(:record)
  login_user
end

it "should delete a record" do
  visit records_path
  find("#record_#{@records.id}").click_link 'Delete'

  page.should have_content "Record has been deleted"
  page.should have_no_content "Record 1"
end
```

Comment: Have you tried `save_and_open_page` after your last test line to see what it on the actual page. It will open your browser and show you if the record was deleted or not.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I wound up doing, but SO wouldn't let me post until today about it because of my level -- thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind - I figured it out with the help of using launchy.

My initial thought was that I was some how losing the "session" and that once the delete link was clicked, then the login page was being displayed again.  That wasn't the case at all.  I did notice though that the header of my app also contained "Record 1" in it.  Therefore the spec would fail for obvious reasons. *Head to desk* - sorry about that, but I figured I'd post my own stupidity and looking way deeper than I needed to.

Comment: If you can, you could try to use the `within` block to isolate where you want to look.